# Any good idea on how to log Google Analytic events on clicks?

Tags: ember.js, google-analytics

Besides log every location changes, I would also like to log these click events as a lot of the time user would click on sth and that click would not update location hash. It would be helpful if it's possible to log these events by intercepting calls made to action helper. I've tried hacking around and no luck so far. I can still log them in the event handlers. It's just feels a little bit verbose. Does anyone have similar problem? Any ideas?

To make it clear, for example instead of in the route or controller having some code like below, the call made to google analytics could being triggered whenever action event fired.

`clickMe: function(){

        App.Analytics.logEvent({category: "userEvent", action: "click", label:"click me", value: 1});

    },`

I've tried to define a customized helper which is basically a wrapper around action helper, it makes a call to log down google analytic events using the information got from its caller and then internally call ember's action helper. I use my own helper in the template to try out, but log events only happened the first time that template rendered. If I keep click on the view no user activity gets logged.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the event bubbling mechanism of javascript to do this. In any Ember view adding a handler named for an event will setup a listener for that event automatically.

By placing such a `click` handler on the `ApplicationView` you can listen in on all clicks for all it's nested views.

```
App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
  click: function(event) {
    console.log('ApplicationView.click', event);
  }
});
```

From here you can use `this.get('controller').send(event)` to notify the controller, route, etc to get to the function that calls the google analytics code.

Comment: I was busy answering other questions and just came back to this one, but you already provided a **perfect answer** Darshan :)

Comment: Thanks for replying the question, Darshan. I feel that I might not making the question clear, what I am trying to tackle is to avoid in  `click: function(event) {
    console.log('ApplicationView.click', event);
  }` make the call to log to google analytics by hand. It would be great if we could make use of action helper to do that for us.

Comment: @Tracy this click handler is a handler that you setup to trap global application clicks, via `ApplicationView`. This avoids having to add custom analytics code to each action handler, since events bubble on their own. Or am I missing something?